# Limpiar datos de formulario php después de dar de alta una persona

Tags: php, html

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de crear un formulario de php, donde se añaden usuarios a una tabla. Todo funciona correctamente, creo, modifico y elimino los datos sin ningún problema. Lo que necesito es que me limpie los datos del formulario al instante en el que doy de alta a una persona, no consigo hacerlo de ninguna manera, trato de poner las variables a null, pero no responde como yo creo que debería.
Gracias por su ayuda.
Este es el código donde doy de alta a los usuarios.

```
    //ALTA DE PERSONA
if (isset($_POST['alta'])) {

    $nif = trim($_POST['nif']);
    $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
    $direccion = trim($_POST['direccion']);

    try {

        validarDatos($nif, $nombre, $direccion);

        //validar que el nif no exista en el array
        if (array_key_exists($nif, $arrayPersonas)) {
            $errores = ("Persona ja existeix <br>");
            $alta = null;
        } else {

            //Crear un array (dentro del arrayPersonas) con el valor del nif y guardar la persona.
            $arrayPersonas[$nif]['nombre'] = $nombre;
            $arrayPersonas[$nif]['direccion'] = $direccion;

                // Limpiar formulario si es correcto

                $nif = $nombre = $direccion = null;

            //mensaje de alta efectuada, he creado una variable nueva porque debe ir al lado del boton
            $alta = "Alta efectuada";       

        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $errores = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Este es el código completo, por si acaso necesitan verlo en su totalidad.

```
<?php
session_start();

//Incorporar funciones externas
require('utilidades/validarDatos.php');

$filasTabla = "";

//array para guardar las personas
$arrayPersonas = $_SESSION['personas'] ?? [];

//ALTA DE PERSONA
if (isset($_POST['alta'])) {

    $nif = trim($_POST['nif']);
    $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
    $direccion = trim($_POST['direccion']);

    try {

        validarDatos($nif, $nombre, $direccion);

        //validar que el nif no exista en el array
        if (array_key_exists($nif, $arrayPersonas)) {
            $errores = ("Persona ja existeix <br>");
            $alta = null;
        } else {

            //Crear un array (dentro del arrayPersonas) con el valor del nif y guardar la persona.
            $arrayPersonas[$nif]['nombre'] = $nombre;
            $arrayPersonas[$nif]['direccion'] = $direccion;

                // Limpiar formulario si es correcto

                $nif = $nombre = $direccion = null;

            //mensaje de alta efectuada, he creado una variable nueva porque debe ir al lado del boton
            $alta = "Alta efectuada";       

        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $errores = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
//BAJA DE LA PERSONA SELECCIONADA EN LA TABLA

if (isset($_POST['bajaPersona'])) {

    $nifBaja = $_POST['nifBaja'];

    if (array_key_exists($nif, $arrayPersonas)) {

    }
}
//validar nif informado
if (!empty($nifBaja)) {
    //validar que el nif existe en el array
    if (array_key_exists($nifBaja, $arrayPersonas)) {
        //borrar la fila del array  

        unset($arrayPersonas[$nifBaja]);
        //mensaje de baja efectuada
        $alta = "Baja efectuada";
    }
}

foreach ($arrayPersonas as $nif => $persona) {
    $nombre = $persona['nombre'];
    $direccion = $persona['direccion'];

    $filasTabla .= "<tr>
    <td class='nif'>$nif</td>
    <td><input type='text' value='$nombre' class='nombre'></td>
    <td><input type='text' value='$direccion' class='direccion'></td>
    <td>
        <form method='post' action='#'>
            <input type='hidden' name='nifBaja' value='$nif'>
            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-warning' name='bajaPersona'>Baja</button>
        </form>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary modificar' onclick='trasladarDatos(this)'>Modificar</button>
    </td>
</tr>";
}

// Ordenar el array de personas por NIF
ksort($arrayPersonas);

//BAJA DE TODAS LAS PERSONAS

if (isset($_POST['baja'])) {
    $arrayPersonas = array(); // Limpiar el array de personas
    $_SESSION['personas'] = $arrayPersonas;
    $filasTabla = null;
    $alta = "Bajas efectuada";
    $nif = $nombre = $direccion = null;
}


//MODIFICACION DE LA PERSONA SELECCIONADA

//recuperar los datos sin espacios en blanco -trim()-
if (isset($_POST['modificar'])) {
    $nifModi = trim($_POST['nifModi']);
    $nombreModi = trim($_POST['nombreModi']);
    $direccionModi = trim($_POST['direccionModi']);


    validarDatos($nifModi, $nombreModi, $direccionModi);

    if (array_key_exists($nifModi, $arrayPersonas)) {

        $arrayPersonas[$nif]['nombre'] = $nombreModi;
        $arrayPersonas[$nif]['direccion'] = $direccionModi;

        $alta = "Modificación efectuada";
    }
    $filasTabla = "";
    foreach ($arrayPersonas as $nif => $persona) {
        $nombre = $persona['nombre'];
        $direccion = $persona['direccion'];

        $filasTabla .= "<tr>
      <td class='nif'>$nif</td>
      <td><input type='text' value='$nombre' class='nombre'></td>
      <td><input type='text' value='$direccion' class='direccion'></td>
      <td>
        <form method='post' action='#'>
          <input type='hidden' name='nifBaja' value='$nif'>
          <button type='submit' class='btn btn-warning' name='bajaPersona'>Baja</button>
        </form>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary modificar' onclick='trasladarDatos(this)'>Modificar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>";
    }
}

//CONSULTA DE PERSONAS:

//ordenar el array por nif

//confeccionar las filas de la tabla de consulta

//volcar el contenido del array en la variable de sesión
$_SESSION['personas'] = $arrayPersonas;
?>
<html>

<head>
    <title>PLA03</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1 class='centrar'>PLA03: MANTENIMIENTO PERSONAS</h1>
        <br>
        <form method='post' action='#'>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="nif" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nif</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nif" name='nif' value='<?= $nif ?? null; ?>'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" value='<?= $nombre ?? null; ?>'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <label for="direccion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dirección</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" value='<?= $direccion ?? null; ?>'>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label for="nombre" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name='alta'>Alta persona</button>
            <span>
                <?php echo $alta ?>
            </span>
            <br>
            <span>
                <?php echo $errores ?? null ?>
            </span>
        </form><br>

        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr class='table-dark'>
                <th scope="col">NIF</th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">Dirección</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
            <?= $filasTabla ?? null ?>

        </table>

        <form method='post' action='#' id='formularioBaja'>
            <input type='hidden' name='baja'></input>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id='btnBaja' name='baja'>Baja personas</button>
        </form>

        <!--FORMULARIO OCULTO PARA LA MODIFICACION-->
        <form method='post' action='#' id='formularioModi'>
            <input type='hidden' name='nifModi'>
            <input type='hidden' name='nombreModi'>
            <input type='hidden' name="direccionModi">
            <input type='hidden' name='modificar'>
        </form>
    </main>


    <?php echo ("<pre>" . print_r($arrayPersonas, true) . "</pre>"); ?>
    <script>

        /* var botonBaja = document.querySelector('#btnBaja');
        
        botonBaja.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (confirm("¿Estás seguro?")) {
        document.querySelector('#formularioBaja').submit();
        }
        }); */
        function trasladarDatos(boton) {
            let tr = boton.closest('tr');

            let nifModi = tr.querySelector('.nif').innerText;
            let nombreModi = tr.querySelector('.nombre').value;
            let direccionModi = tr.querySelector('.direccion').value;

            document.querySelector('[name=nifModi]').value = nifModi;
            document.querySelector('[name=nombreModi]').value = nombreModi;
            document.querySelector('[name=direccionModi]').value = direccionModi;
            document.querySelector('#formularioModi').submit();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tienes varios formularios en el código, ¿cuál es el que quieres limpiar? ¿Cuál es el código que estás intentando? ¿Hay alguna restricción en el ejercicio? Desde Javascript puedes llamar a [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) para limpiar el formulario.

Comment: Hola A. Cedano, gracias por contestar. El formulario que quiero limpiar es el formulario de alta. En el primer código que he puesto en la pregunta, tengo esta instruccion " $nif = $nombre = $direccion = null;" Que debería eliminar los datos del formulario al dar de alta a la persona y dejarme el formulario limpio para poder añadir más usuarios. Espero haberme explicado mejor. En principio lo debería hacer con php, con javascript solo se me permite confirmar las bajas y modificar los datos.

Comment: No tiene demasiado sentido hacerlo desde PHP, no es por criticar al profesor, pero, eso de querer enseñar cosas que no tendrían utilidad ninguna ¿? Si te indican que debe ser desde PHP entonces habría que recargar la página, mostrando el formulario sin datos nuevamente, obligando a renderizar todo de nuevo, etc, etc. En fin ...

Comment: Bueno, yo me ciño al ejercicio, como tampoco acabo de controlar, no se si el error es mío o suyo, tengo que confiar en su criterio y enseñanza. El ejercicio lo tengo completo y funciona correctamente, solo es ese borrado lo que me falla. Es más por la curiosidad y las ganas de hacer las cosas bien, que por el ejercicio en sí, que por un error no me supone nada. Lo haré con Javascript por mi, pero el ejercicio lo entregaré tal cual. Gracias

Comment: Entiendo. Como te decía, si es desde PHP, con que recargues la página, el formulario se limpiará, a condición de que cuando lo crees, no tenga valores por defecto.